# How can I apply CSS on all buttons which are present in that page?

Tags: css

I have created a CSS style class:

```
.btn { 
  color:#050; 
  font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
  background-color:#fed; 
  border:1px solid; 
  border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

How can I apply this CSS style class to all buttons which are present in the page without adding `class="btn"` to every button?

Answer (score 41):

If your buttons are `<input type="button">` or submit, then this should do it:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { 
    color:#050; 
    font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
    background-color:#fed; 
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

Otherwise, if your buttons are `<button>`:

```
button { 
    color:#050; 
    font: old 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
    background-color:#fed; 
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

To grab all three kinds of buttons:

```
button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"] { 
    color:#050; 
    font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
    background-color:#fed; 
    border:1px solid; 
    border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

Comment: i'm using asp.net so its like <asp:button Id="Button1" Text="Button"/>

Comment: How to add Hover in this Scss?

Answer (score 13):

```
button{ 
  color:#050; 
  font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
  background-color:#fed; 
  border:1px solid; 
  border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

OR

```
input[type="button"]{ 
  color:#050; 
  font: bold 84% 'trebuchet ms',helvetica,sans-serif; 
  background-color:#fed; 
  border:1px solid; 
  border-color: #696 #363 #363 #696; 
}
```

Comment: The second example is **not** CSS3. The attribute selector already exists in CSS2.1. It was only expanded in CSS3. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: IMO, this item deserves to be marked as the answer; IOW, I think it deserves a green check mark.

Answer (score 3):

```
input[type=submit], input[type=button], button {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Always add a description to what the code does to make your answer more helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to explicitly set all the styles, but want to use the styles already defined in some pre-existing class (for example the bootstrap btn-default class), you could do something like this:

```
<script>
$("button").addClass("btn-default");
</script>
```

In my case this was what I was looking for, although I'm sure there is some sort of caveat about doing it this way, or you'd expect it was something doable directly from CSS.

Answer (score 1):

just a note

```
input[type="button"]
```

isn't going to work on old browsers like IE6. If that's a problem you will unfortunately need to add your class to each item.