# Dynamically add class to img tag from entire HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have an rich editor which adds text and images,to make the images responsive

```
class="img-thumbnail"
```

is needed in all the image tags,so have used HtmlAgility pack to extract image tags from entire Html but how to add the class on each image tag.

Example

Input from html after extracting image tag

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg">
```

Expected

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
```

Code

```
 public string ParseImage(string pHtml)
    {

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(pHtml);
        var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

        foreach (var item in imgs)
        {
            string orig = item.Attributes["src"].Value;
            //Add class to each img tag.
        }
      }
```

Comment: Why are you not doing this with javascript?

Comment: Cant use javascript as Hosting server doesn't supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in that you need to save the HTML before you display it. Otherwise HTML Agility Pack sometimes omits the changed attributes.

```
public string ParseImage(string pHtml)
{

   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
   doc.LoadHtml(pHtml);
   var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

    foreach (var item in imgs)
    {
        //string orig = item.Attributes["src"].Value;
        item.SetAttributeValue("class", "img-thumbnail");
        //Add class to each img tag.
    }
    using(StringWriter tw = new StringWriter ()){
        doc.Save(tw);
        return tw.ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: how do I add class="img-thumbnail" in img tag,can't create object of TextWriter as its an abstract class.

Comment: Hi I have edited my response, just replace TextWriter with StringWriter

Comment: Ok. but getting <img src="http://domain.com/Image1.jpg">  required             <img src="http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"> how Do i add class in img tag.

Comment: Edited, you shuld use SetAttributeValue

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to all your image tags in css like this

```
.img-thumbnail
{
  // your class property
}

img {
.img-thumbnail
}
```

Here is a similar question.

[I want to apply an existing CSS style to all labels on a page. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153920/i-want-to-apply-an-existing-css-style-to-all-labels-on-a-page-how)

Comment: What kind of var does imgs become?

Comment: var is just a variable declared dynamically,that's it.

Comment: Yes but what kind of element does it become in this instance when you declare it that way? Just trying to see what kind of built in methods you could use on that type.

Comment: @CopyPasterino, Are you sure, is this correct answer, as per as i know you can add property not class in this way

Comment: Not understanding what your trying to say. 
how do I add class="img-thumbnail" in img tag

Comment: @Div Not positive and I'm not on my computer to test but a work around if you can not would be to take the css you have for .img-thumbnail and apply it to all of the buttons instead of adding the class to them all

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.