# How to style input and submit button with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS. How to style input and submit button with CSS?

I'm trying create something like this but I have no idea how to do

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
    Email <input type="text"/>
    Message <input type="textarea"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540380/how-can-i-apply-css-on-all-buttons-which-are-present-in-that-page

Comment: Important thing to note, you **cannot** style it like you would any other element. `<input>` tags don't support things like `::after`.

Comment: Correct. That's why I think it's preferable to use `<button type="submit"><span>Send</span></button>`. You can then use `::after` on the `span`-tag.

Comment: Problem could be, with the `<button>`, an `.addEventListener('submit')`  would not work. The submit event is only triggered on the `<form>` element. So this might be a reason why the OP needs use form. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637920/addeventlistener-using-submit-is-not-working

Answer (score 246):

http://jsfiddle.net/vfUvZ/

Here's a starting point

**CSS:**

```
input[type=text] {
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px solid #ccc; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#333;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 15px; 
    background:#ccc; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Answer (score 79):

Simply style your Submit button like you would style any other html element. you can target different type of input elements using **CSS attribute selector**

As an example you could write

```
input[type=text] {
   /*your styles here.....*/
}
input[type=submit] {
   /*your styles here.....*/
}
textarea{
   /*your styles here.....*/
}
```

**Combine with other selectors**

```
input[type=text]:hover {
   /*your styles here.....*/
}
input[type=submit] > p {
   /*your styles here.....*/
}
....
```

Here is a working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5rjc7/)

Answer (score 27):

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit" />
```

CSS

```
#submit {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0;
 width: 135px;
 height: 60px;
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #0c0 url(image) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}
```

Answer (score 20):

I would suggest instead of using

> `<input type='submit'>`

use

> `<button type='submit'>`

Button was introduced specifically bearing CSS styling in mind. You can now add the gradient background image to it or style it using CSS3 gradients.

Read more on HTML5 forms structure here

> `http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html`

Cheers!
.Pav

Comment: This was very helpful, as Safari for iOS correctly applies my style to buttons, but not to <input type="submit"> :)

Comment: But then you can't specify value as the text on the button, rather as the text between the button tags <button>TEXT</button>

Answer (score 4):

form element UI is somewhat controlled by browser and operating system, so it is not trivial to style them very reliably in a way that it would look the same in all common browser/OS combinations.

Instead, if you want something specific, I would recommend to use a library that provides you stylable form elements. [uniform.js](http://opensource.audith.org/uniform/) is one such library.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria looks like that yes. I updated the link.

Answer (score 4):

For reliability I'd suggest giving class-names, or `id`s to the elements to style (ideally a `class` for the text-inputs, since there will presumably be several) and an `id` to the submit button (though a `class` would work as well):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="text1">Text 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="textInput" id="text1" />
    <label for="text2">Text 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="textInput" id="text2" />
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" />
</form>
```

With the CSS:

```
.textInput {
    /* styles the text input elements with this class */
}

#submitBtn {
    /* styles the submit button */
}
```

For more up-to-date browsers, you can select by attributes (using the same HTML):

```
.input {
    /* styles all input elements */
}

.input[type="text"] {
     /* styles all inputs with type 'text' */
}

.input[type="submit"] {
     /* styles all inputs with type 'submit' */
}
```

You could also just use sibling combinators (since the text-inputs to style seem to always follow a `label` element, and the submit follows a textarea (but this is rather fragile)):

```
label + input,
label + textarea {
    /* styles input, and textarea, elements that follow a label */
}

input + input,
textarea + input {
    /* would style the submit-button in the above HTML */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way based on the answers given here, I hope it helps

```
.likeLink {
    background: none !important;
    color: #3387c4;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    .likeLink:hover {
        background: none !important;
        color: #25618c;
        border: none;
        padding: 0 !important;
        font: inherit;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="submit" style="background: red;" value="PRIVATE">`

last place to be hit in a CSS hi-jack. Ugly but safe. Fastest and hard to change. yes.

Comment: But, doesn't work with restrictive [Content-Security-Policy directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src).

Comment: ahh, thanks for the heads up. appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

When styling a input type submit use the following code.

```
   input[type=submit] {
    background-color: pink; //Example stlying
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this too works great.

```
input[type=submit]{
                 width: 15px;
                 position: absolute;
                 right: 20px;
                 bottom: 20px;
                 background: #09c;
                 color: #fff;
                 font-family: tahoma,geneva,algerian;
                 height: 30px;
                 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                 border-radius: 15px;
                 border: 1px solid #999;
             }
```

Comment: This is completely awful

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS3 Button</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="#" class="btn">Push</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS styling

```
a.btn {
display: block; width: 250px; height: 60px; padding: 40px 0 0 0; margin: 0 auto;

background: #398525; /* old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8DD297 0%, #398525 100%); /* firefox */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#8DD297), color-stop(100%,#398525)); /* webkit */

box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #fff;
border: 1px solid #5ea617;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How to use this like a submit input?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.buttonstyle 
{ 
background: black; 
background-position: 0px -401px; 
border: solid 1px #000000; 
color: #ffffff;
height: 21px;
margin-top: -1px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.buttonstyle:hover {background: white;background-position: 0px -501px;color: #000000; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input class="buttonstyle" type="submit" name="submit" Value="Add Items"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is working I have tested.