# Background color in input fields using class selector

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of various input fields, I try the following and it works nice

```
input[type="text"], textarea {

  background-color : #d1d1d1; 

}
```

but I am wondering why it didn't when I am trying it with class selector:

```
.inputfields {

  background-color : #d1d1d1; 

}
```

my html is

```
<div class="container" >
      <div class="row-fluid" >
          <div class="span8" id="MyProfile">
            <form action="" method="post" id="registerform">
              <p>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
              </p>

              <p>
                <label for="slider" id="agelabel">Age</label>
                <div class="inputfields" id="Ageslider" onclick=""></div>
              </p>

              <p>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="inputfields" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
              </p>
              </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here you go  : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540380/how-can-i-apply-css-on-all-buttons-which-are-present-in-that-page

Comment: It works in JSFiddle. I don't know about you.

Comment: Which browser?  This works in FF.

Comment: as the id suggest `Ageslider` its clearly u use plugins, so they rip off the class names. that why  its not working for you. try to read in the specific docs for that plugin how to preserve or create new class names for the elements.

Comment: if you provide the name of that plugin/framwork of that slider / WYSIWYG we might be helpful ;)

Comment: @Avraam it is also possible that if you use a grid framework that is providing default styles for input-fields, you have to be more specific with your CSS. Since you have to override the frameworks defaults.

Comment: @JohnnyJS I am using bootstrap and JQuerry, but anyway is not something to important, I just wondering why it doesn't work